# How to get state of a View (enabled/disabled)?

Tags: android

How does one check the enabled or disabled state of a `View`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following:

[`View.isEnabled();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Where `View` is a `View` or a subclass of `View`.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs: [`View.isEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isEnabled%28%29)

Returns a `boolean`...